# Unknown syntax in /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

Tags: shell, shell-script, variable-substitution

Looking at the file `/etc/rc.d/init.d/functions`, I can see the following is declaring a number of variables as local variables.  However, why are the variables `killlevel` and `pid_file` have an equal sign after them?

```
killproc() {
        local RC killlevel= base pid pid_file= delay try
```

I'm also seeing the following syntaxes ...  Any idea what `${1##*/}` or `${2:-}` bits are for?

```
base=${1##*/}
...
__pids_var_run() {
        local base=${1##*/}
        local pid_file=${2:-/var/run/$base.pid}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are known as parameter expansion,which is advance syntax of Shell scripting

1. `${2:-/var/run/$base.pid}`  is example of

   ```
   ${VAR :-default }
   ```

   This will result in `$VAR` unless `VAR` is unset or null, in which case it will result in default. In given script, if `${2}` is not set, then default value `/var/run/$base.pid` is taken
2. `base=${1##*/}` is example of

   `${var#Pattern}`

   You can strip `$var` as per given pattern from front of `$var`
   if `f=/etc/resolv.conf` then, `echo ${f#/etc/}` will remove `/etc/` part and get a filename only

UPDATE:

```
f=/etc/httpd/httpd.conf
# This will return etc/httpd/httpd.conf
echo ${f#*/}  
# This will return httpd.conf
echo ${f##*/}
```

Single `#` is non-greedy whereas, double # is greedy approach of matching expression.

Comment: Thanks.  I was testing it out and appears to be coming to the same conclusion but it's good to have someone verifying it.  Just to be clear, base=${1##*/} means strip from the character "#" (there is a second #) and any repetition of it (due to the *) until the character "/"?

Comment: `${var#pattern}` will remove from shortest front pattern and `${var##pattern}` will remove from longest front pattern.

Comment: Okay can you give me an example just to be clear?  I'm not following.  Sorry.

Comment: Also see following link for Parameter Exapsion -http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Comment: @AbhijeetKasurde I edited your post. One typo, but primarily formatting of the enumeration as I suspected you did not know how to indent the code under de standard enumeration syntax on this site. From reading I was not sure if you would wanted the sentence "You can strip..." to be indented under 2. as well, turn that back if you don't want it like that.

Comment: @Anthon I am aware of how to indent the code and syntax of enumeration of list. Sentence "You can strip ..." is explanation of point number 2 and update is also part of point number 2. Thanks for formatting btw.